# Select all where a range of date is in a range of date

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g

```
_______________________________________
|item    |created       |expiry       |
_______________________________________
|A       |01/01/2000    |01/02/2000   |
|B       |01/04/2000    |01/06/2000   |
|C       |01/05/2000    |01/11/2000   |
|D       |01/02/2000    |01/05/2000   |
|E       |01/06/2000    |01/07/2000   |
```

what I wanted is to select all where the values between the created date and expiry date that is between the inputted start_range and end_range.

eg.

```
start_range: 01/03/2000
end_range:   01/05/2000
```

the range above will have the values

```
01/03/2000
01/04/2000 
01/05/2000
```

the output would be like:

```
_______________________________________
|item    |created       |expiry       |
_______________________________________
|B       |01/04/2000    |01/06/2000   |
|C       |01/05/2000    |01/11/2000   |
|D       |01/02/2000    |01/05/2000   |
```

A and E is not included because the dates between them is not in the dates between the start and end ranges.

Comment: Can't you do something like `WHERE DateToCheck BETWEEN Date1 AND Date2` ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
SELECT item,TO_CHAR(created,'DD/MM/YYYY') created,TO_CHAR(expiry,'DD/MM/YYYY') expiry
FROM Table1
WHERE created <= DATE '2000-01-05' AND expiry >= DATE '2000-01-03';
```

Output

```
ITEM    CREATED EXPIRY
B   04/01/2000  06/01/2000
C   05/01/2000  11/01/2000
D   02/01/2000  05/01/2000
```

Live Demo

> http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/bee9f/16

Comment: `created >= DATE '01/03/2000' AND created <= DATE '01/05/2000'` to include `D` also

Comment: Thanks for suggestion @Veljko89

Comment: You must use ANSI format, i.e. `'2000-03-01'`, `DATE '01/03/2000'` does not work.

Comment: in the result set row with item='D' is missing : http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/936c2/2

Comment: Sir you inserted values in different date format. Use the below query for your sqlfiddleLink:   `SELECT item,TO_CHAR(created,'DD/MM/YYYY') created,TO_CHAR(expiry,'DD/MM/YYYY') expiry
FROM goods
WHERE created <= DATE '2000-05-01' AND expiry >= DATE '2000-03-01'`

Comment: you got your answer @BarbarosÖzhan

Comment: @JayShankarGupta ok, excuse me, your demo is OK, i'm voting up yours also.

Answer (score 1):

There is a direct translation of human language to your desired sql:

> select all where the values between the created date and expiry date that is between the inputted start_range and end_range

```
select item, created, expiry
from table
where created between start_range and end_range
   and expiry between start_range and end_range;
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is the solution to your problem:

```
SELECT Item, created, expiry
FROM Table1
WHERE 
created BETWEEN DATE '2000-01-03' AND DATE '2000-01-05'
OR
expiry BETWEEN DATE '2000-01-03' AND DATE '2000-01-05';
```

Follow the link to the demo:

> http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/bee9f/2

**ANOTHER WAY:**

```
SELECT Item, created, expiry
FROM Table1
WHERE created <= DATE '2000-01-05' AND expiry >= DATE '2000-01-03';
```

General Query:

```
SELECT Item, created, expiry
    FROM Table1
    WHERE created <= DATE end_range AND expiry >= DATE start_range;
```

Follow the link to the demo:

> http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/bee9f/7

Comment: @Surface Tension Bro Try the above solution.